# How do I solve this

Tags: jquery, css

So I want the whole page to be over the previous one. But only the background changes and all the texts are visible at once.

Please see for yourself..

```
<style>
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 4em;
}
#a{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.btn{
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    z-index: 999;   
    cursor: pointer;
}
.next{
    right: 0;
    top: 20px;
}
.prev{
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="btn next">Next</div>
    <div class="btn prev">Prev</div>
    <div id="a">    
        <ul>
            <li>aaa</li>
            <li>bbb</li>
            <li>ccc</li>
            <li>ccc</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

and javascript for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li:nth-child(1)').css({'background':'lightgreen', 'z-index':'1'});
    $('li:nth-child(2)').css({'background':'gray', 'z-index':'2'});
    $('li:nth-child(3)').css({'background':'yellow', 'z-index':'3'});
    $('li:nth-child(4)').css({'background':'teal', 'z-index':'4'});
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('#a').css({'height':height, 'width':width});
    $('li').css({'height':height, 'width':width});

    var theFirst = 2;
    $('.next').click(function(){
        if(theFirst == 2){
            $('li:nth-child(2)').animate({'margin-top':'-='+height}, 1500);     
            theFirst++; 
        }else if(theFirst == 3){
            $('li:nth-child(3)').animate({'margin-top':'-='+height}, 1500);     
            theFirst++; 
        }else if(theFirst == 4){
            $('li:nth-child(4)').animate({'margin-top':'-='+height}, 1500);     
            theFirst++; 
        }else if(theFirst == 5){
            $('li:nth-child(5)').animate({'margin-top':'-='+height}, 1500);                 
        }else{
            null;
        }
    });
});
```

and the jsfiddle is:
https://jsfiddle.net/manukarki/wmzskcdq/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to your `li`'s

https://jsfiddle.net/wmzskcdq/4/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('li:nth-child(1)').css({'background':'lightgreen', 'z-index':'1'});
 $('li:nth-child(2)').css({'background':'gray', 'z-index':'2'});
 $('li:nth-child(3)').css({'background':'yellow', 'z-index':'3'});
 $('li:nth-child(4)').css({'background':'teal', 'z-index':'4'});
 var width = $(window).width();
 var height = $(window).height();
 $('#a').css({'height':height, 'width':width});
 $('li').css({'height':height, 'width':width});
 
 var theFirst = 2;
 $('.next').click(function(){
  if(theFirst == 2){
   $('li:nth-child(2)').animate({'margin-top':'-='+height}, 1500);  
   theFirst++; 
  }else if(theFirst == 3){
   $('li:nth-child(3)').animate({'margin-top':'-='+height}, 1500);  
   theFirst++; 
  }else if(theFirst == 4){
   $('li:nth-child(4)').animate({'margin-top':'-='+height}, 1500);  
   theFirst++; 
  }else if(theFirst == 5){
   $('li:nth-child(5)').animate({'margin-top':'-='+height}, 1500);     
  }else{
   null;
  }
 });
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul{
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 4em;
}
li { position: relative; }
#a{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.btn{
 position: fixed;
 background: white;
 z-index: 999; 
 cursor: pointer;
}
.next{
 right: 0;
 top: 20px;
}
.prev{
 right: 0;
 top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="btn next">Next</div>
 <div class="btn prev">Prev</div>
 <div id="a"> 
  <ul>
   <li>aaa</li>
   <li>bbb</li>
   <li>ccc</li>
   <li>ccc</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you :).

Comment: @ManuKarki you're welcome. You probably don't need the z-indexes, either.

Answer (score 1):

Use `relative` position for `li` in css like `position : relative`. `Static` is default.

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` only works in positioning elements. So, in order to put an element over other add `position: relative` to each of them.